# XML LINQ query returns no data

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I experimented with LINQ to XML today, but I wasn't very successful.
When I use a namespace I don't get any data.

Here's the (simplified) xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Message xmlns="urn:protocols:format13">
    <data>
    testdata
    </data>
</Message>
```

I try to get the data with (xmlmsg is a string):

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(xmlmsg);
XNamespace ns = root.Attribute("xmlns").ToString();

List<XElement> datalist =
       (from desc in root.Descendants(ns + "data")
         select desc).ToList<XElement>();
```

But datalist remains empty. If I don't us a namespace it works.

I used XmlReader before, which worked fine with namespaces. But as my xml data gets a little complex to parse, I wanted to use LINQ.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        XNamespace ns = root.Name.Namespace;

        List<XElement> datalist =
               (from desc in root.Descendants(ns + "data")
                select desc).ToList<XElement>();
```

or to why it didn't work; you aren't accessing the *value* of the attribute; this works too:

```
XNamespace ns = (string)root.Attribute("xmlns");
```

or

```
XNamespace ns = root.Attribute("xmlns").Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, root.Name.Namespace did work. XNamespace ns = root.Attribute("xmlns").ToString(); looks pretty similar to XNamespace ns = (string)root.Attribute("xmlns");